# How to add typescript to Vue 3 and Vite project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

My setup: I installed Vue and Vite via the *create-vite-app* module, and then updated all the packages that was generated by 'init vite-app' to the very latest RC versions for Vue and Vite.

Now I want to use typescript for all my code. First I just played around a little bit, and added the *lang="ts"* to the  tag in *HelloWorld.vue*. That seems to work, though I have no idea how typescript gets transpiled from the vue file though.

Then I tried to rename the *main.js* to *main.ts*. Now nothing happen.

I was thinking that I just need to install typescript, but then it hit me, why is it working in the *.vue* component then? Am I doing something wrong if I install typescript now?

Why does typescript work in the vue module (HelloWorld), but no js is generated from the *.ts file?

Comment: Instead of `create-vite-app`, I would do `git clone https://github.com/ktsn/vite-typescript-starter.git`, which uses the latest version of Vue 3 and Vite.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. Also it kind of confirms that the short answer to the main question is, yes, one just installs typscript and then run tsc -w while coding.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

#### How to add typescript to Vue 3 and Vite project

I will create a vite project to use typescript step by step:

- first, we should create a vite project at first

```sh
$ npm init vite-app <project-name>
$ cd <project-name>
$ npm install
```

- second, we should install typescript

```sh
$ npm install typescript
```

- third, we should create a `tsconfig.json` file in the root folder, like this:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  }
}
```

And you can check here, [What is a tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

- then, we sholud create a `shims-vue.d.ts`file in the `src` folder, like this:

```js
declare module "*.vue" {
  import { defineComponent } from "vue";
  const Component: ReturnType<typeof defineComponent>;
  export default Component;
}
```

The `shims-vue.d.ts` file helps your IDE to understand what a file ending in `.vue` is.
Now, we can check whether the `.ts` file works well.
In my case, i rename the `main.js` file to `main.ts` in the `src` folder,
and modify the `index.html`, 12 line:

```html
 <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
```

to

```html
 <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
```

At last, run

```sh
npm run dev
```

If there is no error message, you can create your component file by `.ts`
Good luck!

Comment: I did everything you said but to make it work I had to add `"strict": true` the `compilerOptions` object. 
Source https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/2534#issuecomment-741752908

Comment: Shouldn't it be `npm install typescript --save-dev`?

Answer (score 12):

There is a template for typescript named `vue-ts`.
So running `npm init vite@latest my-vue-app -- --template vue-ts` sets up a typescript vite project.

https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project

UPDATE: reflected Olanrewaju's comment.

Comment: @vitejs/create-app is deprecated, use npm init vite instead

Answer (score 0):

Per the latest [docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project), you can run one of the following commands which will give you the choice of framework and typescript options:

`npm init vite@latest`

`yarn create vite`

`pnpm dlx create-vite`