# "import not found" for custom types in Vue 3 (with Vite/Vitesse)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I've got a Vue 3 project running [Vitesse](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse) (a [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) starter). I've added a custom `ProductData` type to my `src/types.ts`, but when I try to use it in one of my pages the page fails to load and I get a few console errors all saying `SyntaxError: import not found: ProductData`. The path for the import is definitely correct, the type is exported, and I've tried importing from ts files in different locations as well but see the same thing.

Interestingly I do not have any issues importing these types from my `store` files, just from *.vue files. Any ideas? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724523/how-to-add-typescript-to-vue-3-and-vite-project) mentions adding some things to `shims.d.ts` and `tsconfig.json`, but they didn't make a difference.

EDIT: Forgot to include my `tsconfig.json`. This is with `include` from @flydev:

```
// Some items added from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724523/how-to-add-typescript-to-vue-3-and-vite-project
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "incremental": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "types": [
      "vite/client",
      "vite-plugin-pages/client",
      "vite-plugin-vue-layouts/client"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "~/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.js",
    "src/**/*.vue"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

EDIT 2: Just moved over to chrome instead of firefox, and when I check out `types.ts` in `sources`, the file is empty. The error is actually different as well and maybe more helpful: `SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/types.ts' does not provide an export named 'JsonResponse'`.

Comment: Please show us the content of your `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: If it's the same as the one in the repo, you could try to add: `"include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.js","src/**/*.vue"]` after `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: @flydev meant to include that. Just added the tsconfig in an edit. Still seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I came across [this comment in an issue in vitejs/vite](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2117#issuecomment-804444502):

> There is a know issue in Vue with type imports, it should work if you use the import type form:
> `import type { User } from '~/types'`

Changing my import from

```
import { ProductData } from '~/types'
```

to

```
import type { ProductData } from '~/types'
```

seems to fix the problem. Once I fixed my import, I saw the same thing happening with a third-party type, and updating the import fixed that one as well.

Comment: That helps. But I still have the problem that the imported type is not recognized. For example when providing a type for a prop. Did you have the same error?

Comment: No, I don't think I've had that issue. Only thing I can think of is to make sure that you are defining the prop type like `type: Object as YourCustomType`. If you try to use the type without `Object as` then it won't work.